# How do I solve system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have system of linear equations $A\vec{x}=b$ :
$A=\begin{pmatrix}  -2&  1&  -1& 1& 1& \\   1& -1&  1& 1& -2&  \\   3& 0& 0& 0&  -1&  \\   1&  2&  5& 0& 0& \end{pmatrix}$
$\vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}  a \\   b\\   c \\  d \end{pmatrix}$
with initially unspecified numbers a, b, c, d.

How to solve system for the following values of a, b, c, d:

[image]

Can someone help me how to find efficient method of how to bring the three equations simultaneously in a staggered form. How to show that the numbers a, b, c, d must satisfy a linear equation, so that the system is solvable.

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part of your question (staggered form) you have:
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf A}\,{\bf x}_{\,{\bf 1}}  = {\bf b}_{\,{\bf 1}}  \hfill \cr 
  {\bf A}\,{\bf x}_{\,{\bf 2}}  = {\bf b}_{\,{\bf 2}}  \hfill \cr 
  {\bf A}\,{\bf x}_{\,{\bf 3}}  = {\bf b}_{\,{\bf 3}}  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad {\bf A}\;{\bf X} = {\bf B}\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;{\rm columns}\;{\rm of}\;{\bf X} = {\bf x}_{\,{\bf m}}  \hfill \cr 
  \;{\rm columns}\;{\rm of}\;{\bf B} = {\bf b}_{\,{\bf m}}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Comment: But how do it with respect to that

Comment: what you mean by "that"? what is not clear to you?

Comment: how  do I make that A has the sam rank as Ab with respect to a,b,c,d

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: you have more variables than equations, so the answer to 2nd part of your question does not apply. I edited my reply.

Comment: It remains to better clarify what you mean by "solvable", do you refer to A*x=b, or to A*X=B, or do you want a unique vector x to satisfy A*x=B ?